# Is it possible to update different rows of a pytorch Tensor in different ways?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I've had some trouble even finding any people on the internet with this same issue since its quite hard to phrase concisely.. :/

Essentially my issue is I have a pytorch tensor, call it n:

```
tensor([[2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [2., 2., 2., 2.]])
```

and I want to change values of the columns in the following fashion:

```
tensor([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 2., 1., 1.],
        [2., 2., 1., 2.]])
```

i.e. for the first column, I want indices 0:2 to be 1, for the second column, I want indices 0:1 to be 1, etc.

I tried defining start and end tensors in this way, but it didn't seem to work:

```
start = torch.Tensor([0, 0, 0, 0])
end = torch.Tensor([2, 1, 3, 2])
n[start: end] = 1
```

But this doesn't work, and I get a typeError:

> TypeError: only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index

I'm not sure if this is possible with a built in torch operation, or if I'd have to manually iterate through each row of n.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case this is the easiest

```
t = torch.tensor([[2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [2., 2., 2., 2.]])

t[0:2,0] = 1
t[0:1,1] = 1
t[:,2] = 1
t[0:2,3] = 1
print(t)

tensor([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 2., 1., 1.],
        [2., 2., 1., 2.]])
```

Also I do not see why there would be a built in operation to essentially change a value/values in a matrix. Especially since you would still need to give the instructions for which values to change.